# Custom Image for UIButtonTypeInfoLight Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to create a custom Info type button. For the halo effect that goes over the button Image, do I place an ImageView ontop?  Or can i try to add the halo with setImage?  I tried setImage, but it seems when u try to set the halo, which is larger than the actual button, the halo gets resized to the button's bounds.  I tried disabling clipsToBounds, autoresizing mask, and setting contentMode for the button..but none seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. All you have to do is create a generic button (either with `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]` or just `[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:`...`]` and set its `showsTouchOnHighlight` property to YES.